# add ajaxtoolkit to toolbox

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax

How do I show the ajax tool kit in my toolbox in .net? All i see are the ajax server side extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow this http://www.asp.net/Ajax/Documentation/Live/InstallingASPNETAJAX.aspx
Basically you need to download the kit whether 2.0 or 3.5.  Grab the dll file and put it in the bin directory.  Go to your project and reference it.  Right click the toolbox area and create a new area for the ajax kit.  Create the area and select that dll, you will notice all the controls will be added.

Heres a step by step for you:

http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevelopertips/archive/2009/05/16/tip-62-did-you-know-how-to-add-ajax-control-toolkit-to-the-toolbox.aspx

Answer (score 0):

just to clarify, you shouldn't need to add it to the bin directory directly. just add the components from the toolkit to your toolbox, then when you drag a control to your page the underlying references will be created automatically for you.

to add to your toolbox just right click the toolbox and select Add Tab and name it whatever you want. right click that new tab and select Choose Items, browse to ajaxcontrolkit.dll and select it. this will add all of the contained controls to the selection list, and select them as well (indicated with checkboxes). then you just hit ok and all of controls from the toolkit will be present in your new tab.

Answer (score 0):

What I did, so I didn't have to worry about which version of .NET the dll was compiled with, I just added the source code to my solution, so it could build it, and it appeared.

I am using a 64-bit Vista OS, so I wanted to make certain that everything is either 32 or 64 bit, depending on what I am writing.