# How to install AJAX Control Toolkit in visual studio 2022?

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, visual-studio-2022

I have Visual Studio 2022. I want to install ajax control toolkit, but the 20.1.0 installer does not work from the devexpress. Is there a way to get it working?

Answer (score 2):

The installer is an archive that you can open and extract with 7-Zip.

Inside the archive is another archive with the actual files you require.

Extract `.text` from the AjaxControlToolKit.Installer.

Then from there you can extract the `AjaxControlToolKit.dll` for use, as well as other files if desired.

The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868999/) the other answer to add the controls to the VS UI may work if you wish to use the toolbar.

EDIT: AjaxControlToolKit is also available via NuGet.

Comment: The edit is a Huge help and should be promoted.  It is odd they create a download version that won't install in VS2022, but a nugget package will.  May start going to Nuget first before looking around the web fore things like this in development.

Comment: @j.hull It appears to me that the AjaxControlToolKit is/has reached end of life and is no longer being supported.  I'd be happy to be proved wrong some day!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

This is what I did as a workaround:

1. I installed Visual Studio 2019 Community edition on my system.  I got my copy through https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/subscriptions/.  It may be available at other sites as well.
2. Then download and install AJAX toolkit from DevExpress.  It will now install properly and include the AJAX toolkit controls in the Visual Studio 2019 toolbox.  It ***WILL NOT*** include the new controls in the Visual Studio 2022 toolbox.
3. To include the new controls in the Visual Studio 2022 toolbox, follow the instructions at [add ajaxtoolkit to toolbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868999/)

This workaround has worked for me so far.
I hope it works for you!